# Getting no data with express/react/next.js data request using http

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, next.js

## Problem:

I am trying to request data from http://localhost:3000/auth/sendUserData using `http`, but I am getting no data/response (no console.logs).

## What I'm using:

Next.js/React, Node (backend server), getInitialProps (Next.js).

## Code:

#### Userdata.js

```
const http = require("http");
const Userdata = {};

Userdata.getUserData = async function(){
    let url = `http://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/auth/sendUserData`
    console.log(url);
    const options = {
        host: process.env.HOST,
        port: process.env.PORT,
        path: '/auth/sendUserData'
    };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
};

export default Userdata;
```

#### http://localhost:3000/auth/sendUserData

```
{
_id: "5c5521f823a5d183945fd62f",
name: "Saddy",
steamID: "76561198151478478",
__v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with backend authentication since it was rendered on the server and not on the client, causing the session to be lost